# A coin tossing game with two players

Tags: probability

In a coin tossing game two fair coins are given to two persons X and Y each. The game proceeds until one (or both) of the following happens.

1. X wins the game if he gets consecutively two tails for the first time.
2. Y wins the game if he gets a tails immediately followed by a heads for the first time.

Who has the more probability of winning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who has more probability of winning the game?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159702/who-has-more-probability-of-winning-the-game)

Comment: Note:  I have retracted my close vote because, on re-reading, the questions are not exact duplicates.  In the linked question, the two players were working off  a single coin.  Here, with two coins, the problem is different.  In particular, the answer is obviously not $\frac 12$ each since, if nothing else, there is a possibility of a tie.

Comment: Nevertheless, the same techniques apply.  Just describe the possible states of the game (there are not many) and look at the possible transitions between the states,

Comment: Does each person have one coin or two? In the latter case, does only the last toss of the coins matter (assuming that the coins are tossed "consecutive")?

Answer (score 0):

The sample space is (HHHH, HHTH, HHHT, HTHH, THHH, TTHH, HTTH, THHT, THTH, HTHT, HHTT, TTTH, HTTT, THTT, TTHT, TTTT). therefore each person has equal possibilities of winning i.e 2/7.